# Error Cors en produccion laravel y angular

Tags: php, laravel, angular, cpanel

Hola tengo mi api en un dominio con laravel dominio.com y tengo un subdominio que tiene una vista en angular. Tengo configurado mi CORS de laravel de la siguiente  forma:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
       //Url a la que se le dará acceso en las peticiones
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      //Métodos que a los que se da acceso
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
      //Headers de la petición
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization");
```

Y todas las rutas de mi api tienen el cors que configure

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () { rutas }
```

Y tengo tambien comentada esta linea de mi Kernel.php

```
//\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Pero cuando intento hacer una peticion en mi subdominio me aparece:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dominio.com/api/get_info/124124' from origin 'http://subdominio.dominio.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Tambien tengo esta configuracion en mi httacces de mi subdominio

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

En modo local mi vista en angular puede recibir datos sin que se bloquee las peticiones pero ya en el servidor laravel me bloquea todas las peticiones. Es problema con mi configuracion? O problema del servidor? O problema de mi htacces?

Comment: Si haces la petición del dominio al subdominio, entonces es en el subdominio donde debes agregar los encabezados CORS.

Comment: El subdomino hace la peticion al dominio. En este caso Angular (subdominio) le hace la peticion a laravel ( dominio )